# How to display a list of array in a object array in a flatlist with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how to show a list of array data in an object of another array in a flatlist with react native?

this is the list of data below i would like to display in the flatlist

```
const data = [
  {
    students: [
      {
        name: 'crystal',
        city: 'town',
        number: 1,
      },
      {
        name: 'barbra',
        city: 'street',
        number: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

i tried this below but nothing is showing

```
  <FlatList
        data={data.students}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <View>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{item.name}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{item.city}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{item.number}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
```

Comment: `data` looks like an array with a single object inside. Try `data[0].students`. Or perhaps get rid of the outer array if it's not needed.

Comment: @manny check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58534330/6544460 you are using array of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const data = [
  {
    students: [
      {
        name: "crystal",
        city: "town",
        number: 1
      },
      {
        name: "barbra",
        city: "street",
        number: 2
      }
    ]
  }
];
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(data[0].students)
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={data[0].students}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <View>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{item.name}{console.log(item)}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{item.city}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{item.number}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what if the data was like this ```
const data = [
  {
    class: "grade",
    students: [
      {
        name: "crystal",
        city: "town",
        number: 1
      },
      {
        name: "barbra",
        city: "street",
        number: 2
      }
    ]
  }
];;``` how would i get to show the class field with student field in the flatlist at the same time @VahidAkhtar  @Kraylog

Comment: @manny i think both json are same. did you change something in json?

Comment: i added a class field @VahidAkhtar

Comment: @manny you can't loop that because that's outside of array so you can access like this data[0].class.